what is the smallest possible size when creating a luks2 header
What is the smallest possible size when creating a luks2 header?
How to create one under 16 Mib?

You can create a new one with --offset. Shrinking an existing one is not straightforward and would require you to either relocate all data, or change the start offset of the partition.

how can i create a new luks2 header with less than 16 MiB?
